# "Invalid Host header" when visiting React app through domain - Rails backend with Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ruby-on-rails, nginx, webpack

I have a React app with a Ruby on Rails backend being served from a Linux machine I own (not a cloud provider). The React app is served using the `serve` application after being built with `npm run build`, and it makes several HTTP requests to a Ruby on Rails backend that I also run from the same machine. The requests are made using the Axios package. This is the first React app that I'm trying to build and host on my domain, so I'm a bit new to all of this.

I also use Google Domains so that the app can be reached via a domain I own. The app is reachable at http://bt_tokens.jzisser.com. Finally, I use Nginx Proxy Manager as a reverse proxy so I can easily route requests to my domain to different servers on my backend based on the subdomain.

The trouble is, when I try to navigate to the link above, the page simply displays an "Invalid Host header" message instead of loading. Looking in the network tab of my browser, the request results in a 400 "Bad Request" response.

I read up on this a bit and it seems I need to make sure that my request to the URL includes a "Host" header, with the value being the domain name that the request is going to. So for example, for the link above: `Host: bt_tokens.jzisser.com`. I added this to the request by going into the Proxy Host for `bt_tokens.jzisser.com` and adding a custom location as follows:

[image: Screenshot of custom location]

And looking at the network tab, the Host header is being added:

[image: Network tab where Host header is added]

In researching how to fix this, I came across a solution involving editing the `webpacker` config to include `allowedHosts`:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    allowedHosts: 'all',
  },
};
```

The catch here is that I don't have a custom webpacker config, and until now, have had no reason to consider a custom config. Other SO answers have pointed to the `webpacker.config.js` file in the `node_modules` folder, which feels *really weird* to me, but I went ahead and edited the config there to include this block. And I can confirm it's being picked up by `npm run build`, because at one point I accidentally created a syntax error there and the build failed. However, **adding this did not fix the "Invalid Host header" issue**.

Further Googling and searching SO hasn't turned up anything helpful, so I feel like I've hit a wall. Can anyone help me figure out how to fix this, or what I can do to debug this further on my own?

Comment: same issue... anyone an idea? Or maybe the OP found a solution? Highly appreciated

Comment: I haven't yet, sadly :(